# How to conditionally poll messages from Kafka Topic

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I have a few task notifications in a MongoDB database. Each task has a due_date and reminder flag. I am pushing these tasks to a Kafka Topic. There is a Node JS app that polls from this topic and pushes notifications to a frontend app based on the due_date and reminder flag. The due_date could be past dated or upcoming.

From Kafka we need to send notifications to the Node App that is listening whenever those conditions time-based conditions occur:

1. Reminder = true and it is X time before the Due Date
2. Due Date = now
3. The Task still exists and is Past Due

How can this be done with Kafka?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB to Kafka interaction should be via source connector. DB Connectors can publish events to Kafka whenever there is a change in underlying table. So if new rows are created or any column is updated.

So ideal solution would be to introduce some more columns in table OR a new utility table with columns to identify the conditions you mentioned above. May be a column like "IsDueDate" which can be a boolean type. Create a scheduler in DB (not sure of Mongo but most DBs have option for this) Or any batch system (like Spring batch/boot app) to validate your data and populate these columns.

Once these columns are updated, it will trigger a message to Kafka via connector and your front end apps polls Kafka for new messages and ultimately can use these flags in payload to identify which condition triggered this and you can do the stuffs in front end.

Comment: Thank Valath. I have implemented the proposed solution and it's working fine.